# Finding the first specific value horizontally and attaching value to it

Tags: python

I have many columns and want to find the column where 'Y' appears for the first time:

[image]

In this case, it's Col3. Each column means a specific fee, if 'Y' is in Col3, that's $100.

I could write a function something like

```
def fee(x):
    if x[col3] == 'Y':      
        return 100
```

and so on for all columns, but how do I make sure I ONLY get the result for the first 'Y'? I want the fee for Col3, not for Col6.

Comment: Can you define type of x?  Is it a dictionary ? Give sample value of x.

Comment: It can be anything. Each column has a different fee (going from smallest to largest from left to right), and I need to find when the 'Y' occurs for the first time - this will be the fee somebody will pay.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([list('NNYNYYNN'), list('NNNYNYYY')], 
                  columns=[f'Col{i}' for i in range(1, 9)])

# df
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8
0    N    N    Y    N    Y    Y    N    N
1    N    N    N    Y    N    Y    Y    Y
```

You can get columns where a `Y` occurs like this:

```py
>>> df.eq('Y').any()
Col1    False
Col2    False
Col3     True
Col4     True
Col5     True
Col6     True
Col7     True
Col8     True
dtype: bool
```

Which can be used to filter `df.columns`:

```py
>>> df.columns[df.eq('Y').any()]
Index(['Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8'], dtype='object')
```

So all you need to do is get the first element from the filtered Index:

```py
>>> df.columns[df.eq('Y').any()][0]
'Col3'
```